# « Il a été constaté » ou « Il était constaté »

Tags: temps-grammatical, passé-composé, imparfait, passif

Soit la phrase

> Il a été constaté que les élastomères chargés après relaxation
>   convergent vers un état dit stationnaire ou encore d’équilibre.

et sa variante

> Il était constaté que les élastomères chargés après relaxation
>   convergent vers un état dit stationnaire ou encore d’équilibre.

En termes de la grammaire, c'est voix passive du passé composé contre voix passive de l'imparfait ; en termes du sens, dans ce contexte, quelle est la différence ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- La première phrase indique que la constatation a eu lieu dans le passé et qu'elle est terminée.
- La deuxième indique que la constatation était en cours alors qu'autre chose, à préciser, avait lieu.

C'est donc la première phrase qui est à priori correcte.

Answer (score 1):

L'explication est spécialisée au domaine de la recherche scientifique et technologique, mais elle reste valide pour les domaines de la vie en général après avoir fait les changements appropriés de vocabulaire.

**1** Dans le cas de la voix passive du passé composé on relate un fait  dans le processus de recherche dans le passé qui s'est répété ou non ; il suffit d'une fois pour que l'emploi de cette forme soit correcte ; mais le plus souvent lorsqu'un auteur utilise ce temps et cette voix il s'agit d'un contexte  de plusieurs occurrences d'un fait scientifique.  Ce fait peut être une conséquence recherchée ou tout simplement un résultat accessoire, quelque chose qui a été remarqué en passant. Assez souvent aussi l'auteur citera ces occurrences.

- Il a été constaté que telle et telle chose se passe, par X en 1931, par Y en 1938, et par d'autres chercheurs.

**2** Dans le cas d'utilisation de la voix passive de l'imparfait il s'agit de la narration d'un fait précis dans un déroulement de faits connectés (il peut y avoir eu des répétitions), qui est **souvent** le processus de recherche, soit le processus à court terme de l'expérience en laboratoire, soit le processus à long terme de la recherche plus complexe qui demande des séries d'expériences et des analyses plus longues et possiblement par des chercheurs indépendants. Ce fait peut être une conséquence recherchée ou tout simplement un résultat accessoire.